# Getting error with ASCII to raster: The error is says that my asc file doesn't have a file extension

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, esri-ascii-raster

The dataset that I'm using is http://fme.ceh.ac.uk/fmedatadownload/results/FME_656D6600_1478695468793_27958.zip

I'm on a Windows 8, 8 GB pc
I'm using ArcMap 10.3.1

Comment: Did you unzip it?

Comment: Yeah I did, I also tried to get the NCOLS 480
    NROWS 450
    XLLCORNER 378922
    YLLCORNER 4072345
    CELLSIZE 30
    NODATA_VALUE -32768

Comment: Yeah I did, I also tried to Ncols and Nrows under each other instead of next to each other and that didn't help either

Answer (score 1):

No problem with gdalinfo

```
gdalinfo PHTR.LCM2007_GB_1K_DOM_TAR_V2_.asc
Driver: AAIGrid/Arc/Info ASCII Grid
Files: PHTR.LCM2007_GB_1K_DOM_TAR_V2_.asc
Size is 1056, 528
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (-7.107181753135650,54.548261546965719)
Pixel Size = (0.008984102950029,-0.008984102950029)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -7.1071818,  54.5482615)
Lower Left  (  -7.1071818,  49.8046552)
Upper Right (   2.3800310,  54.5482615)
Lower Right (   2.3800310,  49.8046552)
Center      (  -2.3635754,  52.1764584)
Band 1 Block=1056x1 Type=Int32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=24
```

Perhaps ArcMap does not like the filename, try to rename PHTR.LCM2007_GB_1K_DOM_TAR_V2_.asc into something simple like fme.asc.

Answer (score 1):

There must be something in your environment, or you got a bad copy of the download. That is the only thing I can think of. Try restarting and then run ASCII to Raster again. The unzipped asc file worked for me.

[image: Input Parameters]

[image: Result]